# Android Custom Camera getMaxZoom() returns zero in S2

Tags: android, android-camera, zooming

I have added following code for implementing zoom in camera. In S2  getMaxZoom() return zero  and works in other devices. S2 device camera is also able to zoom.

```
private void handleZoom(MotionEvent event, Camera.Parameters params) {
        int maxZoom = params.getMaxZoom();
        int zoom = params.getZoom();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "maxZoom "+maxZoom);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "zoom "+zoom);
        float newDist = getFingerSpacing(event);
        if (newDist > mDist) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "handleZoom 1");
            // zoom in
            if (zoom < maxZoom)
                zoom++;
        } else if (newDist < mDist) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "handleZoom 2");
            // zoom out
            if (zoom > 0)
                zoom--;
        }
        mDist = newDist;
        params.setZoom(zoom);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "handleZoom 3 "+zoom);
        mCamera.setParameters(params);
    }
```

Comment: what does parameters.getZoomRatios() return you? The list contains supported zoom ratios.

Comment: parameters.getZoomRatios()  returns 100

Comment: S2 is known for having these problems related to params.getMaxZoom() :-(

Answer (score 0):

There can be a case where Api for zoom might not be supported on a specific device.

Use `params.isSmoothZoomSupported()` to see if its supported on the device which its running and you can write your code around that.

```
if(params.isSmoothZoomSupported()){

//zoom

}else{

//handle if its not supported

}
```